# JQuery val() into ASP form not recognising on 'Submit'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm in real need of some ASP and AJAX help, which i don't have much exposure of, and unfortunately, the CMS that I'm working with is written in ASP, so my hands are tied.

The problem:
I have a button that runs a JQuery function to change the value of an input field within the asp form. When I click the button, the value of the field changes and is displayed in the textbox. But when I come to submit the form the value isn't recognised, i.e it clears the value.
If I manually update the input field with the same value as what the button would input, the value is recognised when I submit the form. So it works, but it's manual, which is what I'm trying to avoid.
The entire value of the field is also recognised and submitted if I was to click the button and then go into the input field and add a space after the current value.

What I've tried:
I've used JQuery to trigger events for change, focus, keypress, keydown, keyup, blur, etc - but have had no joy in resolving the issue. I've also tried simulating the manual process of typing using Daniel Wachsstock's "Sendkeys" plugin, http://bililite.com/blog/2008/08/20/the-fnsendkeys-plugin/, also no resolution.

My question:
- Are there common events or triggers that happen in ASP or AJAX that I'm likely to be overlooking?
- Can anybody point me in the right direction to research an answer?
- Is there some sort of hidden field that updates as I type but not as I use $('#inputid').val('newvalue');

Additional:
To add to the frustration of this puzzle, I can't share my code outside of the company I'm working for. I know, it makes the question vague and it's like trying punch in the dark. That is why I've only posted the question now that all my other routes of bug fixing have been exhausted.

Thanks for any suggestions you can give.

Comment: `submit` event of a form perhaps? If you press enter, the value is empty, because pressing enter by default submits the form. This means you've now bypassed the click event handler on the button.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding a click handler to a button it's better to capture the submit event of the form. This only holds up if the form is using an actual "submit" button:

```
<button type="submit">submit</button>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

You can still bind an anchor tag as a submit event, but then it's also clear if the anchor triggers a submit event from the JavaScript logic. If not, which is still doable, then you don't need a a form at all. The form tag with form fields and fieldsets and so on, provide a basic usabilty feature, like tabbing through fields or pressing enter to submit.

---

So try to change the functionality to this:

```
$('form#your-special-id').on('submit', function(){
    var hiddenField = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]');

    hiddenField.val('please change');
});
```

---

Most likely you'll have something like this:

```
$('button#your-special-id').click(function(){
    var form = $('form#your-special-id'),
        hiddenField = form.find('input[type="hidden"]');

    hiddenField.val('please change');

    form.submit();
});
```